# How do you know which way to measure an angle (is it $40$ or $140$ degrees)?

Tags: geometry

I've noticed the most protractors have the numbers running both ways.  For example, if reading from the left side to the right, it may show $0$ to $180$ and $180$ to $0$.

Does it matter or how do you know which direction to read the measurements?  For example would an angle that looks like this _\ (sorry for the poor drawing) be measured as, say, $40$ degrees or $140$ degrees?

Comment: You define the angle for an ordered pair of rays. For the two rays in your picture, which one is the first ray and which one is the second? If the first ray is the horizontal ray (pointing W) and the second is the NW one, then the angle is the one covered by rotating the first ray counterclockwise until it overlaps the second. Therefore, 320. If the first ray is the NW one and the second the horizontal, then 40. The angle would be 140 for a pair of rays, the first pointing E and the second the original NW in your picture.

Comment: You need to read the angles from the same scale. And the difference is what matters, besides orientation. So either 40 or 320.

Answer (score 4):

See in the picture below how you estimate the angle looking like _\

As a rule of thumb, an acute angle is always smaller than 90 degrees, whereas an obtuse angle is always between 90 degrees and 180 degrees. The angle below is therefore approximately 45 degrees.

[image: This is how you estimate the angle]